# Change UINavigationbar title according to UICollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Im trying to change the title of `UINavigationbar` title according to `UICollectionView` cell `indexPath.row`, I have horizontal `UICollectionView` cells like Photo sliding-content (as Photo app in IOS).

What i am trying to achieve is when i move from indexPath.row for example from 1 to 2 to change the title but i am having one issue, I've placed the following code in `cellforitematindexpath` or `willdisplaycell` :

```
self.title = "\(indexPath.row+1) of 2"
```

This code works fine but it has one issue, which is when i start dragging to the next cell but i return to where am i, the title changed to be 2 but i am still in 1 ! which is really annoying !

I've tried also to place the code in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` but it has the same issue, like i started dragging but i changed my mind to stay on cell 1 so the method says okey its end dragging, then the title again changes to 2 but i am still in one.

I need to since if i am still where am i then i don't have to change the title, if i am completely in the next cell then change the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was happening because method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` was called to prepare second item, but first cell is still in memory and method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` was not called when you return to first.
Try this:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(nonnull UIScrollView *)scrollView {
        float currentPage = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
        NSLog(@"Current page: %f", ceil(currentPage));
}
```

Don't forget to add `UIScrollViewDelegate`in your CollectionViewController.h

Comment: It was the best to place the code in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, it works !